# Trying to make quiz slider, but script not working

Tags: javascript, php

I am making quiz for my website..questions are appearing ..i want to change the question with next button..it just shows one question and when i click next button new question should appear which is not appearing ..

This is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","studhelp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


?>
<?php
$cat=$_POST['cat']; // to get the category
$qus=qus_show($cat);



?>


 <?php 


/* .....function which will fetch data and display question ....*/

 function qus_show($qus){

     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","studhelp");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $resultQue=mysqli_query($con,"select * from questions  where cat_id='$qus'  order by rand() limit 4");
  $no_of_rows=mysql_num_rows($resultQue);
  ?>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Online test</h2>
  <form method="post" action="answer.php">
  <?php 
  $i=1; //question number

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultQue)){
$row;     ?>
<?php if($i==1){?>         
                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"> <?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $row['question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="0" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-1'];?>
                   <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="no_attempt" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>
                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button'>Next</button>
                    </div>     

                     <?php }elseif($i<1 || $i<$no_of_rows){?>

                       <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="0" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-1'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>
                    <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' >Next</button>
                    </div>

                   <?php }elseif($i==$no_of_rows){?>
                    <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
                    <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i?>.<?php echo $result['question'];?></p>
                    <input type="radio" value="0" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-1'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-2'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-3'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio1_<?php echo$row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/><?php echo $row['opt-4'];?>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" id='radio1_<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $row['q_id'];?>'/>                                                                      
                    <br/>

                    <button id='pre<?php echo $i;?>' class='previous btn btn-success' type='button'>Previous</button>                    
                    <button id='next<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='submit'>Finish</button>
                    </div>
 <?php } $i++;} } ?>

                </form>
                </div>
```

This is script that i am using for changing the next question

```
<script>
    $('.cont').addClass('hide');
    count=$('.questions').length;
     $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

     $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
         element=$(this).attr('id');
         last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
         nex=last+1;
         $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

         $('#question'+nex).removeClass('hide');
     });

     $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
         element=$(this).attr('id');
         last = parseInt(element.substr(element.length - 1));
         pre=last-1;
         $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

         $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
     });

    </script>
```

Comment: Please first of check you console if you have any error there .

Comment: There are no errors, i am missing something really obvious..but i cant figure it out